# How to solve this NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I developed application of Google Mobile Add banner by referring [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start%20link).

I had followed all the step but still I am getting the below log after I run my application.

```
AddDemo[2631:123835] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Please help me to solve my problem. My Application target is ios7 and I am running it in ios9.

> I had also added this flag in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

> My code is here.

```
    @import GoogleMobileAds;

        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @interface ViewController : UIViewController
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView *bview;


        @end


        #import "ViewController.h"

        @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);

                self.bview.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-**********************";
                self.bview.rootViewController = self;
                GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

                request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
                [self.bview loadRequest:request];

}
@end
```

> I had also seen that i have to add below code in my info.plist. But I
>   have not any idea what should I have to add instead of
>   ******yourserver.com********

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS9 requires the server to only support TLSv1.2. Probably you set something wrong on ATS (App Transport Security). Check this [blog](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)